# Facebook extended permissions stream_publish is not working anymore?

Tags: facebook, fbjs

I know I might not get any help here, but I've been on this all day and starting to loose my mind.

Here's the thing: no matter the method I choose I can't ask the user for the extended permission `publish_stream` from my Facebook-connected website since last thursday (it was working perfectly fine before and I made 0 changes to the code since then). I also looked for any changes in the API but couldn't find any.

I can ask for any other permissions, but if I try to add `stream_publish` to the list it doesn't work. There is no error or anything, it just doesn't ask for the permission.

Any idea on what the problem could be?

Also: a [link to a related bug on the FB bugtracker](http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11484).

Answer (score 0):

It was and has always been called `publish_stream` and not `stream_publish`. The set of permission/scope names are documented here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions. It works as expected when I try it: http://fbrell.com/bugs/publish-stream-permission